# Charset error on replication

Tags: mysql-replication, mariadb

I'm trying to set up replication between two MariaDB databases, but I get the following error in phpMyAdmin:

```
Error 'Character set '#610' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file'
```

I checked `mysqld --verbose --help` and both have UTF-8 as their default charsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment. Check also all other character set definitions.

## default charset variables

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
```

## show default data encoding

Databases:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME, DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```

Tables:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ENGINE, TABLE_COLLATION FROM TABLES LIMIT 1000;
```

Columns:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME, CHARACTER_SET_NAME, COLLATION_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE CHARACTER_SET_NAME IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1000;
```

I added a limit statement to only show the first 1000 rows. Adapt for example with: `WHERE CHARACTER_SET_NAME = '#610'`

To show all abailable charsets:

```
SHOW CHARACTER SET;
```

Hope that helps finding the problem.

Comment: I apologize, I ended up nuking and reinstalling the entire OS and that fixed it. I hadn't gotten around to deleting this question yet, so I'll just leave this in case it helps someone else.